# How do I build only the Emacs C source files and not the Elisp source files in the Emacs repository?

Tags: build

Running the default procedure:

```bash
~/emacs $ mkdir build
~/emacs $ cd build
~/emacs/build $ ../configure
~/emacs/build $ make
```

Results in building both the C source files and the Elisp source files.

What command (or target) do I have to pass to `make` in order for me to build JUST the C source files?

Answer (score 4):

> Running the default procedure:

If you're in a checkout of the Emacs repository, as the OP title suggests, then there's a missing step there: the `configure` script is generated by the `autogen.sh` script, so you need to run the latter first.

If instead you're in a release tarball, then the generated `configure` script is already included.

> Results in building both the C source files and the Elisp source files.

Note that release tarballs already include the byte-compiled `.elc` files, so they will not be recompiled by running `make`.

> What command (or target) do I have to pass to `make` in order for me to build JUST the C source files?

The Emacs sources are organised such that many subdirectories have their own makefile, and most of the C sources are under the `src` subdirectory.

So I think the easiest way to build (mostly) just the C sources is via `make -C src temacs`.  This builds a bare Emacs executable called `temacs` that lacks any of the usually preloaded Elisp libraries like `lisp/subr.el` or `lisp/simple.el`.  Actually, this target will also generate some charset files, but at least it won't byte-compile Elisp.

Alternatively, `make -C src` will additionally byte-compile the necessary preloaded Elisp libraries, and dump a functional `emacs` executable.  This avoids byte-compiling most auxiliary Elisp packages, such as Gnus or Org.

Note that there are also some auxiliary C sources under `lib-src`, such as those for `emacsclient`.  Run `make -C lib-src` or similar to build those.

See [`(info "(elisp) Building Emacs")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Emacs.html) for more details on how Emacs is bootstrapped.